# Is it possible to access a variable from the caller's scope inside a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, scope, closures

This question has been asked before, but all of the popular questions are 5+ years old and I'm curious to know if anything has changed since then. If you have a function that's defined somehwere

```
const accessParentScope = () => parentVariable;
```

then is there any way to access a `parentVariable` from the scope where the function is called? The end goal would be to do something like

```
function createAnotherScope() {
  const parentVariable = 'some value';
  return accessParentScope();
}
```

and have `accessParentScope()` have access to `parentVariable` *without* explicitly passing it as an argument.

Alternatively, is it possible to access variables from the scope of a closure? If you have a function like

```
function createClosure() {
  const parentVariable = 'some value';
  return closure = () => null;
}
```

then can you do something like `createClosure().parentVariable`? The syntax here obviously won't work, but I'm curious if anything remotely like this is possible.

Comment: that's what function arguments were invented for - to pass values to a function

Comment: No, and no (and no, this is not gonna change). What do you think you need this for, what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: Another 5 years later and still not possible. :'(

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to access a variable from the caller's scope inside a function in JavaScript?

No. That would be [**dynamic scope**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping). Most languages (including JavaScript) implement [**lexical scope**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping). That is not going to change.

There is `this`, but it's rather an explicitly passed argument. The value of `this` is (in most cases) determined when the function is *called*, not when or where it is defined (arrow functions treat `this` differently though).

```js
function logName() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

function sayFoo() {
  logName.call({name: 'foo'});
}
sayFoo();

function sayBar() {
  logName.call({name: 'bar'});
}
sayBar();
```

As you can see, there really isn't any advantage of this over defining the function with parameters:

```js
function logName(name) {
  console.log(name);
}

function sayFoo() {
  logName('foo');
}
sayFoo();

function sayBar() {
  logName('bar');
}
sayBar();
```

As @JaromandaX said in their comment, that's what parameters are therefore, to provide values to the function at call time.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to access a `parentVariable` from the scope where the function is called?

No.  The only way is if the context where the arrow function was declared has that attribute or variable available.

```js
var parentVariable = 'Ele from SO'; // This is the variable available to the below arrow function (window context).
const accessParentScope = () => parentVariable; // or this.parentVariable

function createAnotherScope() {
  const parentVariable = 'some value';
  return accessParentScope();
}

console.log(createAnotherScope())
```

> Alternatively, is it possible to access variables from the scope of a closure?

Yes, that way you can access the declared attributes and local variables.

```js
function createClosure() {
  this.parentVariable = 'some value'; // Note that this is an attribute (global as well) rather than a local variable.
  return closure = () => this.parentVariable;
}

console.log(createClosure()());
console.log(parentVariable);  // Access to global variable/attribute
```

> Then can you do something like createClosure().parentVariable?

No, what you can do is to set an attribute to the returned function.

```js
function createClosure() {
  var closure = () => closure.parentVariable
  closure.parentVariable = 'some value';
  
  return closure;
}

console.log(createClosure()());
console.log(createClosure().parentVariable)
```

Comment: In your first example, `const accessParentScope = () => parentVariable;` would works as well. No need for `this`. In your second example, `this` is either the global object (so your are implicitly creating a global variable) or `undefined` (in which case the code throws an error).

Comment: @FelixKling 1.) yes, 2.) yes